# "First flight" is to "maiden voyage" as "final flight" is to....?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe the final flight of an aircraft (or other vessels if there is no direct equivalent) such as the final flight of the space shuttle.

Does anyone know if a word like this exists? Thanks!

Comment: "Last voyage" or "final voyage".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Swan song**?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swan_song):

> The swan song is a metaphorical phrase for a final gesture, effort, or performance given just before death or retirement. The phrase refers to an ancient belief that swans sing a beautiful song in the moment just before death, having been silent (or alternatively, not so musical) during most of their lifetime. This belief, whose basis in actuality is long-debated, had become proverbial in Ancient Greece by the 3rd century BC, and was reiterated many times in later Western poetry and art.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it the "Fair Well Voyage" .. "Swan Song" is a little too "before death" to be a good fit for me.

Comment: "Fair well" or "farewell"? Also, it would be helpful to back this up to show that it's both used and unambiguously understood.

Answer (score -2):

How about "swan song?" Adding more text because "swan song" isn't 30 characters long...

Comment: Ninja'd, sorry :-)

Comment: The solution to "swan song" not being 30 characters long isn't to add useless filler text, but to add some reasoning behind why you think this is a good answer.